# Start SE sites with a tag blocklist

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, blocked-tags

Despite meta tags being [discouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) now, the [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) beta managed to get three posts tagged [subjective] in the first three or four hours of the beta. Should SE sites start with a blocklist of certain bad tags that have a propensity for popping up on every SE site?

Comment: While I like the `subjective` tag, it would be a good idea to start with the blacklist, if it's going to be implemented later anyway.

Comment: Yes, please. On the UI beta there was a 'UI' tag within hours.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure I agree -- I think each site should establish what its own community norms are without being held to the norms of a programming site.

That said, I do expect some standards to emerge, but I'd rather watch and learn than being overly prescriptive from the beginning.

edit: we do now support the concept of "intrinsic" tags, that is:

- [apple] on apple.se
- [wordpress] on wordpress.se
- [unix] on unix.se
- [drupal] on drupal.se
- [ui] and [ux] on ux.se

In other words, an intrinsic tag is one that functionally "exists" on every question because it is at the site level.

This intrinsic tag feeds the blocklist and also works to vet and validate question migrations to make sure they are somewhat valid; migration candidates must have at least one tag in common on the target site including the intrinsic tags for the site.

Comment: Well, [subjective] has nothing to do with programming; it's the same on every site. It comes down to if you want [the death of meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to be SO-specific, or universal across all the SE sites

Comment: What do you think of my ideas in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61354/allow-10k-users-to-vote-on-suggested-blacklist-tags/61371#61371)?