# Allow 10K users to vote on suggested blacklist tags

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, blocked-tags

There are lots of requests popping up to blacklist meta tags. Could we get a feature for 10K users to propose and vote on tags for the blacklist? (And, maybe, to un-blackist tags, too).

Answer (score 21):

<sup>I'm putting this in an answer so I don't make a ridiculously long comment.</sup>

With regards to the [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list), this part of the feature request was definitely `[status-declined]`, but Jeff put `[status-completed]` on the question because they have a back-end sort of tool for it.

Regardless of my comment on [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list/49418#49418), I've mostly come around to his thinking on this. It really is a dangerous thing to be blacklisting tags.

However, I think it's reasonable that moderators (diamond mods) should be able to manipulate that system, for one simple and very important reason: moderators are the highest level of authority *with domain knowledge for the site* (in the general case). The fact is that having a moderator delegate to a developer is an unnecessary extra step, because in most cases, the developer can't validate the request anyway. (Now that I think about it, how *would* this process work for the new Stack Exchange sites?)

What form would a moderator-only system take? It could be a proposal/voting system with a low quorum (say, two mods have to agree to add/remove a tag to/from the blacklist), or it could simply be a list. But I definitely think mods should be able to manipulate this system.

Comment: The big game changer that happened since that original post was that we are now anti-meta-tags. There are limitless meta-tag possibilities, which I think require a more available system to manage.

Comment: @Jon: Agreed, but I still don't think that's a job for 10k's. Diamond mods seems like the best balance, to me at least. Moreover, "we" does not mean Stack Exchange sites. If those sites want to have meta-tags, that's *that* community's decision.

Comment: at a minimum, what about a way for xxx-rep users to *propose* a tag ban? That way we don't have to have countless MSO questions about it.

Comment: @Jon: I think this kind of proposal needs to have discussion/justification attached. With tag synonyms, you can see immediately why a synonym is proposed (at least most of the time). But with an ambiguous tag, for example, even if the questions are already cleaned up, it's not obvious why that tag would be proposed for blacklisting.

Answer (score 3):

Please allow us to vote up or down, not just approval.

It's so frustrating not to have down arrows when you have up arrows.

Comment: Why do you have to be so negative? :)

Comment: I bring balance to the force. :)