# Tag blacklist request:[apple] on Apple.SE

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-block-request

Could the tag `[apple]` be put on the blacklist at Apple.SE? It's currently a synonym for `[apple-inc]`, but we've found that doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: +1 [I still say](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61354/allow-10k-users-to-vote-on-suggested-blacklist-tags/61371#61371) tag blacklisting should be a moderator-level (as opposed to dev-level) utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great idea -- I added `^apple$` to the tag blacklist on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @Jeff... makes our lives easier :P

Comment: Also thanks for actually linking to apple.stackexchanage.com. As a newb sans clue I just spent ten minutes trying to figure out what this "apple.se" thing was that I kept seeing here in Meta.