# Post-split pre-migration tag burnination/management/befuddlement

Tags: support, tags, meta

Looking at the first 20 pages of tags, I see a few things that could be done to fix tags here and make the migration process less painful later:

- Most of the questions with these tags should probably also be tagged [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) so that they're included in the migration: [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [cleanup](/questions/tagged/cleanup)  [facebook.stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/facebook.stackoverflow) [portuguese-stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/portuguese-stackoverflow) and maybe [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) [sponsored-tags](/questions/tagged/sponsored-tags)
- There's also, for some reason,  a bunch of questions tagged  [superuser](/questions/tagged/superuser) [serverfault](/questions/tagged/serverfault) [programmers-se](/questions/tagged/programmers-se) [wordpress-se](/questions/tagged/wordpress-se) [codereview-se](/questions/tagged/codereview-se) [math-se](/questions/tagged/math-se) [so-addon](/questions/tagged/so-addon) [askubuntu](/questions/tagged/askubuntu)
- Some tags are now as useful as a "videogames" tag on Arqade: [all-sites](/questions/tagged/all-sites) [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) [stackexchange-2.0](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-2.0)

Comment: [I don't think they want to migrate all of the SO-specific questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014/229487#comment753455_229487).

Comment: @Dukeling They want to migrate _some_ of them, I dunno how, but if they do only look at the [tag:stackoverflow] tag they'll miss out on other SO specific stuff.

Comment: Presumably, that last set should be made into [intrinsic tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60425/start-se-sites-with-a-tag-blacklist/62183#62183) for this site.